# Initialize R data.table with column name from string

Tags: r, data.table

I want to do something like this:

```
> colname <- "a"
> dt <- data.table(colname = c(1,2,3,4))
   a
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
```

But instead, I get this:

```
> colname <- "a"
> dt <- data.table(colname = c(1,2,3,4))
   colname
1:       1
2:       2
3:       3
4:       4
```

Is there a good way around this besides creating the `data.table` and assigning the names afterward?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `setnames`.  The advantage of `setnames` is it can be used to name either all the columns or a subset of columns by providing the names in the `old` and `new` argument

```
dt <- data.table(c(1,2,3,4))
setnames(dt, colname)
```

---

We can wrap `setnames` while creating the object itself

```
dt <- setnames(data.table(c(1,2,3,4)), colname)[]
dt
#   a
#1: 1
#2: 2
#3: 3
#4: 4
```

Comment: I said I wanted a way to do this besides creating the `data.table` and assigning the names afterward. Is there a way to do it in one line?

Comment: @user3685285  Yes, it can be done in one line,   I updated the post

Comment: @user3685285  Another option is `structure`, but that is a bit lengthy way instead of the clean `setnames` i..e `structure(list(c(1, 2, 3, 4)), .Names = colname, class = c('data.table', 'data.frame'))`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do so without using `data.table` is using the base function `names`

```
> colnames <- "a"
> dt <- data.table(c(1,2,3,4))
> dt
   V1
1:  1
2:  2
3:  3
4:  4
> names(dt) <- colnames
> dt
   a
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
```

If you have a data frame with multiple columns, just pass the vector of column names to the function `names`.